# angular-route doesn't seem to activate automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm currently having an issue with the angular-route@1.5.8 module.

The router does not seem to activate on its own. What I mean is that when I call the page (http://localhost/index.html), the requested template does not show up. However, manually adding a hash (#) to the end of the url, activates the router and shows the correct template.

I build a test application with nearly the same router-configuration, and in that app the router works as expected.

There are no errors logged in the console.

This is the config:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
       .config(function ($routeProvider) {
           $routeProvider
               .when('/', {
                   templateUrl: './app/html/default.html'
               })
               .when('/login', {
                   templateUrl: './app/html/login.html',
               })
               .otherwise({
                   redirectTo: '/'
               });
    });
```

The templates are basically a span-tag with some text to show what template is being displayed.

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put ng-view directive on your index page? You should share more of your the relevant  routing codes, your html, your templates.